# Change numerical plot labels on one axis to strings

Tags: plotting, labeling

This question likely has a straightforward answer.
Suppose I have a plot something like this:

```
ListPlot3D[Table[RandomInteger[10], {5}, {20}], 
  InterpolationOrder-> 0, Filling -> Bottom,
  FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None,
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}][#2] &)]
```

[image]

I would like the $y$-axis labels to be `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday` rather than `{1,2,3,4,5}`. But the $x$- and $z$-axes labels can remain
with their numerical values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListPlot3D[Table[RandomInteger[10], {5}, {20}], 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Bottom, 
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}][#2] &),
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {{1, "Monday"}, {2, "Tuesday"}, {3, "Wednesday"},
    {4, "Thursday"}, {5, "Friday"}}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! And my apologies for not knowing about this.